# Get the position from div top from last elment in scrollable div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get the position from div top from the last elment in a scrollable div with jQuery?
I have tried this but it doesnt work:

```
let bES = $(id).children().last().scrollTop()
console.log(bES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) method to read its `top` property :

```js
let bES = $('#content').children().last().position().top
console.log(bES)
```

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <input value="123">
  <input value="456">
  <input value="789">
</div>
```